# Adwords Ad type issue

Tags: google-api, google-ads-api

I am trying to create ad for adgroup but getting following error:
 `faultString: [AdError.INVALID_AD_TYPE @ operations[0].operand.ad]`

this is my code:

```
AdGroupAdProxy adGroupAdProxy= new AdGroupAdProxy(session, services);
adGroupAdProxy.createNewAd("TextAd", "http://example/12123.html", adGroupId);

public Long createNewAd(String adType, String displayUrl, Long adGroupId) throws ApiException, RemoteException{

Ad newAd = new Ad();
newAd.setAdType(adType);
newAd.setDisplayUrl(displayUrl);

AdGroupAd newAdGroupAd = new AdGroupAd();
newAdGroupAd.setAd(newAd);
newAdGroupAd.setAdGroupId(adGroupId);

AdGroupAdOperation operations = new AdGroupAdOperation();
operations.setOperand(newAdGroupAd);
operations.setOperator(Operator.ADD);

    Long adId = adGroupAdService.mutate(new AdGroupAdOperation[] {operations}).getValue(0).getAd().getId();
    return adId;

}
```

I was looking into Ad types which should be supplied to API but no luck to find it. Could you please point me to my problem?

Answer (score 2):

In Google AdWords, there are several different advertising networks that a campaign can target.  Search Network is for text ads; Display Network is for image ads.  Some campaigns only target a single network, while others target both.

It is likely you are trying to upload a text ad to a "Display Network only" campaign.

It is also worth noting that, when indicating ad type within a mutate operation, you actually specify xsi:type rather than Ad.Type (looks like this would be handled in your AdGroupAd class, but just thought I'd be thorough!).

Answer (score 0):

I've seen a problem that should be similar to this problem. It's setting the type of the ad. You should not set the type using:

```
newAd.setAdType(adType);
```

But instead create a certain type of *Ad* by creating a different object based on the *adType* string you're recieving as a parameter. Perhaps you could even pass an object with the parent type *Ad*. As you're reading this it probably sounds a bit vague. Let me demonstrate:

```
AdGroupAdProxy adGroupAdProxy= new AdGroupAdProxy(session, services);
adGroupAdProxy.createNewAd(new TextAd(), "http://example/12123.html", adGroupId);

public Long createNewAd(Ad newAd, String displayUrl, Long adGroupId) throws ApiException, RemoteException{

newAd.setDisplayUrl(displayUrl);

AdGroupAd newAdGroupAd = new AdGroupAd();
newAdGroupAd.setAd(newAd);
newAdGroupAd.setAdGroupId(adGroupId);

AdGroupAdOperation operations = new AdGroupAdOperation();
operations.setOperand(newAdGroupAd);
operations.setOperator(Operator.ADD);

    Long adId = adGroupAdService.mutate(new AdGroupAdOperation[] {operations}).getValue(0).getAd().getId();
    return adId;

}
```

This way the Adwords library will take care of the type internally.

This is also done in the following PHP example (it should quite the same for Java), they use a TextAd instead of just an Ad. [See line 53](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-php-lib/blob/d22d6be8c9667b5a07c170e4f838701fbf7f6400/examples/AdWords/v201409/BasicOperations/AddTextAds.php)

P.S. I know this question is a bit old, but it fixed the problem for me, so it might also do so for others ;)